# electron: javascript wait for asynchronous

Tags: javascript, promise, electron, bonjour

I'm using electron to develop a desktop app that must discover an app running on android devices using bonjour.

I have it working with the package bonjour downloaded with:

```
 npm install bonjour
```

The code is:

```
 var bonjour = require('bonjour')();
 bonjour.find({ type: 'http' }, function (service) {
      if (service.port == 2222)
      {
            ipsArr[indexIpsArr] = service.host;
            indexIpsArr++;
      }
    })
```

It is working, and it is saving the ips of the devices in the array.

Now the problem is I have to wait until it finds all the ips and work on that array. I'm not used to develop in this asynchronous way in javascript, I have been trying with the npm q package, introducing the concept of promise, but I haven't been able to make it work.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Please show us your attempt at using promises.

Comment: Does `find` call its callback multiple times?

Comment: yes, it is called multiple times. There is no attempt, I saw the documentation here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/q , but I don't know how to apply here.

Comment: You cannot use promises for events that occur multiple times.

Comment: How do you know *when* it found *all* the IPs?

Comment: mmmm, ok. The only solution that comes to my mind is reloading the contents of the HTML any time the event occurs.